# Fullscreen image scrolling with mouse

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I want to make a fullscreen image (opened with lightbox Expand image) that is overflowing the screen size to scroll with the mouse overing of the sides or corners of the window -> eg. when the mouse is in the right corner - the image scrolls to the right, if it is in the bottom right corner - to the right and bottom.

Is there any jQuery plugin which can accomplish this? 
Or a HTML5/CSS3 method?

Comment: please provide fiddle example.

Comment: Basically it is a Pretty photo script, that needs this implemetation: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/
As I see it makes the image full size (as original - opposed to fit to viewport), and also the container div to fit it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this snippet, it works like a charm with a little tweaking:

```
// Variables for current position
var x, y;

function handleMouse(e) {
  // Verify that x and y already have some value
  if (x && y) {
    // Scroll window by difference between current and previous positions
    window.scrollBy(e.clientX - x, e.clientY - y);
  }

  // Store current position
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
}

// Assign handleMouse to mouse movement events
document.onmousemove = handleMouse;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give following styles to image.

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```